# Best Seed Drill for Planting Perennials with Small Seeds in a Large Garden Area?

Tags: seeds, planting, germination, perennials

I am planning to plant a variety of perennials on a 1000 m2 area in my garden, and the seeds I'll be using are quite small. I want to achieve a precise and efficient planting pattern with 10cm spacing between each seed in rows and columns. The list of plants includes species like Scutellaria incana, Eupatorium maculatum ‘Riesenschirm’, 'Transparent' Molinia litoralis, and many others.

I'm looking for recommendations on a suitable seed drill or planter that can handle small seeds and provide the desired spacing accurately. The cost of the seeds is a factor, so the 10cm spacing is chosen for efficiency.

Can anyone suggest specific models or brands of seed drills that have proven effective for similar projects? Any insights into the practical use of these drills for planting perennials with small seeds on a larger scale would be highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help!